# android :how to communicate between activities, or how to hold the instance of each other

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B, B is a dialog mode ,  A start B, both them can visible. During both activities running,  how to communicate each other?
one method is register BroadcastReceiver at each activity. but BroadcastReceiver  can't get result of each sendBroadcast(i): it is safe:

```
        // at ActivityA onCreate
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ...//receive msg
            }
        };
        Log.i(TAG,"register broadcast");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                "xxx1"); //"xxx2" in ActivityB
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and when some happened at ActivityB:

```
        Intent i = new Intent("xxx1"); // "xxx2" at activityA
        ...//some paramters
        sendBroadcast(i);

        Log.i(TAG,"send status");
```

Comment: are you sure A is even running once B starts? I would think onPause() would be called on it when it goes behind B. You can't have more than one activity running at the same time.

Comment: yes, its run. because is dialog mode.

Comment: doubt it, another activity coming to the foreground is going to cause onPause() to be called even if it's a dialog, why don't you put in some Log statements and see.

Comment: You can use the methods in Michael's answer, or consider using SharedPreferences, writing a file, or a few other things depending on your needs.

Comment: From the developer page - "An activity can frequently transition in and out of the foreground—for example, onPause() is called when the device goes to sleep or when a dialog appears."

Comment: actually, I have done that way( in each activity register a BroadcastReceiver) in my other apps many times.

Comment: Well then you probably have a race condition where onResume() of the first activity is called before the broadcast is propagated. As you can see it doesn't always work (and no guarantee it will work for all users and all devices in your other apps) and you need to re think your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to hold on to the instance of the Activity because it can cause pretty bad memory leaks.
Activities can be recreated on any config change such as device rotation or keyboard change, and in this case a new Activity instance will be created and your reference will be for the old activity instance.

There's a few things you can do to exchange data with activities.
(In order from best/easiest - to more difficult)

1) If it's a simple one way data exchange you can send a `Bundle` of data when starting an `Activity`. See (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

2) You can use `startActivityForResult` which will open an `Activity` for the purpose of returning some result of data. See (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

3) A bit more complicated, but you can use an EventBus mechanism with pub/sub behavior like Otto (http://square.github.io/otto/)

Comment: my problem is communicate when them running. not only A start B or B finished.

Answer (score 1):

Both activities are NOT running simultaneously.

When A starts B, the sequence will be as below( I have ommited other lifecycle events which depend on the individual code of your activities):

> `onPause()` of A *[foreground lifetime ends for A]*
>   `onResume()` of B *[foreground lifetime starts for B]*
>   ...B ends...
>   `onPause()` of B *[foreground lifetime ends for B]*
>   `onResume()` of A *[foreground lifetime starts for A]*

(since B is a dialog which partially covers A). When B finishes, `onResume()` of A gets invoked.

When A starts B, the `foreground lifetime` of A finishes, but `visible lifetime` of A continues because A is still partially visible (in background of B).

So for your question **`During both activities running, how to communicate each other?`**
Answer: At any point of time, only one activity is running (i.e has foreground lifetime and can interact with the user). *Both activities are NOT running simultaneously.*

The [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) clearly mentions:

> **The visible lifetime** of an activity happens between a call to onStart() until a corresponding call to onStop(). During this time the user can see the activity on-screen, ***though it may not be in the foreground and interacting with the user.***
>
> **The foreground lifetime** of an activity happens between a call to onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). `During this time the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user.`

Comment: I think activity' running means its main thread running.there has other thread, just like MediaPlayer, or some thread created.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please trying by using FragmentActivity. Activity A is your main FragmentActivity  and Activity B is Fragment display Activity B as and Use Static Variable to interchange values. I'm not sure about it.